# Set-AzureWebsite: No default subscription has been designated.

Tags: powershell, azure, release-management, ms-release-management

I am using VSTS Release Management. In my release flow I add a task 'Azure PowerShell(Run a PowerShell script within an Azure environment)' to run a simple script to set some key vaues in the web.config of a web app:

```
Set-AzureWebsite -Name $AzureWebsiteName -AppSettings $appsettings
```

When I run the deployment, I get the following error (related to the script):

### [error]No default subscription has been designated. Use Select-AzureSubscription -Default  to set the default subscription.

The task is configured to use the connection type "Azure Resource Manager" and so far I understood that 'Set-AzureWebsite' should be used in classic mode?
Is there another way to set the AppSettings with the Azure Ressource Manager Mode=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [name](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/whats-new-with-azure-app-service/) Azure websites changes to Azure App Service Web Apps in the ARM, so you can use: `Set-AzureRmWebApp`

Comment: Yes, After updated the suggested changes, it worked

Answer (score 0):

**Replace below command:**

```
Set-AzureWebsite $webAppName -AppSettings $appSettingsHash
```

**With this command:**

```
Set-AzureRmWebApp -AppSettings $appSettingsHash -Name $webAppName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
```